# Strings with date and time to timestamp DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have two fields with strings:

```
Date_field, Time_field
20001215, 1105
20201215, 1203
```

How can I create a timestamp with these?
This works but I need the time as well:

```
Select to_date(Date_field, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Results in:

```
2000-12-15 00:00:00.0
2020-12-15 00:00:00.0
```

Desired results:

```
2000-12-15 11:05:00.0
2020-12-15 12:03:00.0
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your table has _columns_, not fields. (And a date has a year field, a month field and a day field.)

Comment: Go from date to timestamp - and then add the time?

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Thanks all.
Im answering my own question:

```
Select to_date(Date_field||' '||Time_field,'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')
```

Results in desired format:

```
2000-12-15 11:05:00.0
2020-12-15 12:03:00.0
```

Answer (score 0):

cristians answer seems better to me, I'd use that over my answer generally. I'll keep mine as it  may still help others.

You are most of the way there, obviously it would be nice if you could use two columns in `to_date()` but as i don't think this i possible then the best alternative is probably to use [timestampadd](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_timestampadd.html)

note the following example from the documentation:

> Example 1: The following example will add 40 years to the specified
> timestamp. An interval of 256 designates years, while 40 specifies the
> number of intervals to add. The following statement returns the value
> '2005-07-27-15.30.00.000000'.
>
> SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(256,40,TIMESTAMP('1965-07-27-15.30.00'))
> FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;

So after your existing to_date call use the `timestampadd` with the value from the `time_field` on the result of the `to_date`. That should give you the output you desire.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @Cristian your solution was better, maybe not idiomatic but more understandable. +1.